# The import javafx.scene.control.Alert cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I am getting the error with following two imports in Eclipse:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
```

The errors are: "*The import javafx.scene.control.Alert cannot be resolved*" and same is true for the 2nd import statement.

I am using Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) and have installed e(fx)clipse with latest JDK 1.8 (1.8.0_45).

There is no problem with other javafx related import statements, such as

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
```

Comment: Can you make sure that eclipse is using the installed JDK i.e. 1.8.0_45? Alerts were introduced in Java 8u40, so if eclipse is using any level lower than this, it will throw compilation errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot  ItachiUchiha :) I installed the latest JDK 1.8 update 45 but eclipse was still using the JRE 1.8.0_20. I have changed this now and problem has been fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes,thx for remind me update the JDK to ```1.8.0.45```+.
My steps below:

1. install the right JDK (1.8.0_45 +),mine 1.8.0_60.
2.update my path variable to new JAVA_HOME && JDK's \jre\bin  directory.
3.open eclipse(version 4.4+ support ```java8``` )->window->preferences-> java->Installed JREs,click the edit btn in the right panel to update the directory to new jdk's bin  ,mine is ```D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65```,then all fixed :)
[ps. The last step fixed Nadeem's problem about eclispe still use the old JRE.]

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, until I installed the JDK 1.8.0_60. That's right, installing the latest JDK helped!
[image]

After you install the latest JDK, change the settings on the Eclipse
There are two steps to the process:

1. Select the appropriate JRE in `Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` as shown here:
   [image]

   2. In `Project > Properties > Java Build Path`, Add Library as depicted below:
      [image]

Comment: This answer worked to me, should be marked as accepted. Or if it didn't work to the guy who made question he should explain something more.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem on Eclipse (MacOSX Yosemite) this morning but yesterday everything worked... To solve the problem I just deselected the checkbox for another JDK in `Project > Properties > Java Build Path` restarted Eclipse, reselected the good one (JDK 1.8.0_60), restarted Eclipse again and voilà ! Just a weird bug with checkboxes...

Hope it ll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the java version.
Java 1.8.0_45 do not include javafx.scene.control.Alert 
You can download version 1.8.0_221 [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)