# The import org.eclipse.fx cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to create a OSGI JavaFx project in Eclipse. I get the following errors ***(Commented out below)***

```
import org.eclipse.fx.ui.theme.AbstractTheme; // The import org.eclipse.fx cannot be resolved

public class DefaultTheme extends AbstractTheme { // AbstractTheme cannot be resolved to a type
    public DefaultTheme() {
        super("theme.default", "Default theme", DefaultTheme.class.getClassLoader().getResource("css/default.css"));
    }
}
```

How can I get the imports to work right?

I installed **e(fx)** on my Eclipse to help with JavaFx development.

> > e(fx)clipse
> >     e(fx)clipse is an Eclipse plugin to author JavaFX 2.0 application
> >     Copyright (c) 2011-2012 BestSolution.at Systemhaus GmbH. All rights reserved.

**UPDATE**

java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: What Java version are you running?

Comment: @Swagin9 java version "1.8.0_60"

Comment: Just to make sure, is your Java compiler using that version in your workspace?

Answer (score 0):

First step with "Import cannot be resolved" errors in Eclipse: re-create the Eclipse project.

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` or your equivalent. Then refresh the project in Eclipse to see if it's still happening.

EDIT: This person seems to have had the same problem and fixed it: [e(fx)clipse The import of javafx cant be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389150/efxclipse-the-import-of-javafx-cant-be-resolved)

There also this:

[Some javafx classes cannot be resolved in Eclipse using Java SE 8u25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011734/some-javafx-classes-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse-using-java-se-8u25)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have recreated the project multiple times, but to no success, @Koen De Groote

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev I did quick search and found someone who claims to have fixed it.